# Detect a knock/clap to iPhone/iPad

Tags: ios, accelerometer, gyroscope, core-motion

I am planning to develop an gyroscope based project like TipSkip, handle event knock to device from behind or detect a clap ,I searched google but I didn't find anything except core motion guide and event handling guide.
Thanks for any help

Comment: NiravBhatt gave you a good suggestion on the clap-detection. As for detecting a knock: you will probably have to use a high-pass filter on accelerometer data and figure out the details with a bit of experimenting. Your question (the topic of it) seems interesting. But it is missing one important part: the list of things and approaches that you've tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Detecting a clap requires audio recognition i.e. frequency analysis. There is no better source than Apple's own [AurioTouch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/aurioTouch/Introduction/Intro.html) example for FFT. There is fairly good material about FFT and auriotouch online as well, like [this](http://www.kevatron.co.uk/understanding-auriotouch/).

As for the knocks, accelerometer is the way to go and you just need value recognition for the kind of movements your knock generate.

Comment: I had download AurioTouch but don't know in detail how to detect clap. could you edit your answer for more detail?